# generate dynamic task using hooks without running them in backend

Tags: python, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple dag - that takes argument from mysql db - (like sql, subject)
Then I have a function creating report out and send to particular email.

Here is code snippet.

```
def s_report(k,**kwargs):
body_sql = list2[k][4]
request1 = "({})".format(body_sql)
dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn")
df1 = dwh_hook.get_pandas_df(request1)
df2 = df1.to_html()
body_Text = list2[k][3]
html_content = f"""HI Team, Please find report<br><br>
        {df2} <br> </br>
        <b>Thank you!</b><br>
        """
return EmailOperator(task_id="send_email_snowflake{}".format(k), to=list2[k][1],
subject=f"{list2[k][2]}", html_content=html_content, dag=dag)

for j in range(len(list)):
mysql_list >> [ s_report(j)] >> end_operator
```

The s_report is getting generated dynamically, But the real problem is hook is continously submitting query in backend, While dag is stopped still its submitting query in backend.
I can use pythonoperator, but its not generating dynamic task.

Comment: `...that takes argument from mysql db`. 

Is this this question for MySQL database? You have it tagged with the Snowflake database tag but not the `mysql` tag.

Comment: Hey Aditiya, can you post your entire dag please? This will help me with debugging. Second, you say that the "hook is continuously submitting query in backend". What do you mean by that?

Comment: df1 = dwh_hook.get_pandas_df(request1), This is generating a dataframe, if we check in snowflake warehouse, every 30 second its submitting the same query, My question is how I can make the dag so that, query should submit only during the runtime of entire dag. Basically I need to have autocommit as false.

Comment: @AdityaDhanraj answered below.... if any follow-ups let me know

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

By looking at your code, in particular the lines:

```
for j in range(len(list)):
mysql_list >> [ s_report(j)] >> end_operator
```

we can determine that if your first task succeeds, namely, `mysql_list`, then the tasks downstream to it, namely, the s_report calls should begin executing. You have precisely `len(list)` of them. Within each s_report call there is exactly one `dwh_hook.get_pandas_df(request)` call, so I believe your DAG should be making `len(list)` calls of this type provided `mysql_list` task succeeds.

As for the mismatch you see in your Snowflake logs, I can't advise you here. I'd need more details. Keep in mind that the call `get_pandas_df` might have a retry mechanism (i.e. if cannot reach snowflake, retry) which might explain why your Snowflake logs show a bunch of requests.

If your DAG finishes successfully, (i.e. `end_operator` tasks finishes successfully), you are correct. There should be no requests in your Snowflake logs that came post-DAG end.

If you want more insight as to how your DAG interacts with your Snowflake resource, I'd suggest having a single `s_report` task like so:

```
mysql_list >> [ s_report(0)] >> end_operator
```

and see the behaviour in the logs.